# why and how to solve 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined' for ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in bootstrap modal. The data in ckeditor should be loaded dynamically after ajax call. I am not able to load the data in ckeditor.
Code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Thank you Message</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                <?php $ckeditor->editor('message', '', array('id'=>'editor1')); ?>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```
$(document).on('click', '#sendemail', function(){
    var target = $('#hidden_send_email_url').val();
    var id = $(this).find('#hidden_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : target,
        data : {id : id},
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data){
            var modal = $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            modal.find('.modal-body input#recipient-name').val(data.to)
            modal.find('.modal-body input#subject').val(data.subject)
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(data.message)
            
            
        },
        error : function(){
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    })
})
```

Error is:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined
How to solve this?
Any help/suggstion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Try checking the output from `console.log(CKEDITOR.instances)`. Either the editor has not been instantiated yet or it's name is set to something other than 'editor1`

Comment: @mark.monteiro Thanks solved the problem.

Comment: where can I check editor name

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue by removing the `id` attribute from the `textarea`

Comment: This is actually the only trick that got mine working. Any Idea why it wont work with an ID on it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the editor is "Ready" find out how to listen for the ready event then do ur value assigning in there. I had similar issue in vue and my ready event is called ready `<ckeditor @ready="onEditorReady" v-model="editorValue"></ckeditor>`

So i run my assignment in that listerner. Im sure its similarish outside vue context too.

```
  methods:{
    onEditorReady() {
      const note = UserLessonNote.query().where("id", parseInt(this.$route.params.lessonId)).first()
      if (note?.content) {
        this.UserLessonNoteContent = note.content
      }
    }
  }
```